# How to update Drawer navigator dynamically on login and change its content?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I have created sidebar using drawer navigator. I want to change sidebar contents when user logs in ie I want to update state values(isguest, ismember) each time sidebar opens. however, Sidebar component is mounted only once and I am not able to update state values. ComponentDidMount is working only once.

Below is my App.js file.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
       <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Welcome" drawerPosition='right' options={{unmountOnBlur:true}} drawerContent={(props) => <Sidebar {...props} />} >
        <Drawer.Screen  name="Welcome" component={Welcome}  options={{unmountOnBlur:true}}/>
        <Drawer.Screen  name="Home" component={Home}  options={{unmountOnBlur:true}}/>
      </Drawer.Navigator>

      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

export default App;

This is My Sidebar.js file:-
I want to update state values (isMember and isguet) each time side bar is opened.

```
async componentDidMount() {
              AsyncStorage.getItem("LOGIN_TOKEN").then((value) => {
              if(value == 'true'){
               this.setState({isguest: false });
               this.setState({ismember: true});
             }
             else {
              this.setState({isguest: true });
              this.setState({ismember: false});
             }
         })
         .then(res => {
            //do something else
        });
  
}
```

Comment: Howdy  ! I think you may want to get this piece of info higher up the tree and then access it from the components that may need it. In other words, grab `AsyncStorage.getItem("LOGIN_TOKEN")` from the App somewhere and pass it's value to the sidebar. Then when the state of the user changes, you can leverage `useEffect` to perform any ops. 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle#react-navigation-lifecycle-events

Hope this helps!

Comment: I use class based coding and I dint know how to use useEffect with that. Everything comes back to componentDidMount. I am Updating Login_Token is initial route itself. Can you provide code sample as how to pass props to sidebar.js from welcome.js(parent)

Comment: I think an understanding of basic app architecture would help you get further in less time. The docs point out that the `componentDidMount` method is not called on subsequent visits to a navigation screen; only the first time (which is expected). You may want to brush up on how they advise handling authentication, since that's your main goal right now: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow